# Table-Layout: have one row get all space required (because of rowspan)

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablelayout

I havea few complex data-table and am facing a problem with they layout: there is one cell wich gets a rowspan across all other rows, but the content of that cell is variable in height and may well exceed space required by all other rows.

something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td style="height: 20px;">bla1</td><td rowspan="3">supa-col!</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height: 20px;">bla2</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height: 20px;">bla3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, lets look at that table again with a larger "supa-col":

```
<table>
<tr><td style="height: 20px;">bla1</td><td rowspan="3" style="height: 200px;">supa-col!</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height: 20px;">bla2</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height: 20px;">bla3</td></tr>
</table>
```

What happens when this is rendered is that the additional vspace required to include the rowspaning call gets distributed equally across the height of **all** cells.

What I would prefer is that space to be appended at the bottom of the last row, so that the distance between row 1 and 2 does not change. In other words: the size of that supa-col should not have an impact on the layout of all other calls...
(I'd also be happy to append a final row which could get all the vetical filling that is needed...)

*(Of course, in the real world, I do not know (or set) the heights in advance...)*

Comment: would like to help but i need more clarification....whats the point in the rowspan? you only have one row per...also the 2nd to last paragraph...so you want all the table cells to be same size, and append extra sizes after the data? i made a fiddle. maybe you can add to it. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/cH9f6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the height attribute from the last one...

```
 <tr><td>bla3</td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought about that this morning while showering and it's not good to see your confirmation and even better: it actually works! :)

Comment: Oh well - when I tried to implement this, problems continued :((
see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140663/ie-and-ff-render-my-table-unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertical-align on the td's. Css

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

or

```
<table>
  <tr><td style="height: 20px;vertical-align:top;">bla1</td>
  <td rowspan="3" style="height: 200px;vertical-align:top;">supa-col!</td></tr>
  <tr><td style="height: 20px;vertical-align:top;">bla2</td></tr>
  <tr><td style="height: 20px;vertical-align:top;">bla3</td></tr>
</table>
```